# Everything in an IFrame Loaded event

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, onload

Is there some sort of event for IFrames that only fires when every resource (script, image, stylesheet, dom) has loaded? Basically I want to have a loading graphic displayed over the IFrame and only remove that when everything is loaded inside so the user doesn't see everything loading.

Currently I am using `$(iframe).ready(function() { ... });` but this fires very early before anything has loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `window.onload` event.

`window.onload` fires if anything (images, iFrames, etc.) was completly loaded, that is why most guys dislike this event pretty much. But in your case, it seems to fit.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   alert('fired');
});
```

non-jQuery

```
window.onload = function(){
   alert('fired');
};
```